# EntityFramework show entities before saving changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

Entity Framework ObjectSet with its method ToList shows just saved entities. That means, when I call

```
context.AddToCustomers(myNewCust);
```

and then (without calling SaveChanges)

```
myDataGrid.DataContext = context.Customers.ToList();
```

the DataGrid doesn't show the newly added entity (even `context.Customers.Count()` doesn't include it).

Is there any way to show these entities (those with `EntityState = Added`) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can get unsaved added entities by calling something like:

```
var inserted = context.ObjectStateManager
                      .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                      .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity)
                      .OfType<Cutomer>();
```

But just by reading your question, I'm affraid that you are trying to do something wrong. Why do you need to combine unsaved entities with retrieved? If you need to show unsaved content you should simply keep it in your own separate collection.

Comment: "Why do you need to combine unsaved entities with retrieved?" Perhaps you have an Entity in a form with related children entities displayed in a list - you want to add new children to the list but only persist the children when they save the parent entity.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the  TryGetObjectStateEntry(EntityKey, ObjectStateEntry) method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx